# How do I remove a character from a list or string in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, erl

How do I remove the character `/` from this list (or call it a string)

```erlang
List = "/hi"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Erlang variables are immutable and

```
List = "/hi".
```

binds `List` to the expression `"\hi"`, you cannot simply remove anything from `List`; in fact, you cannot alter `List` in any way as long as it remains bound.

What you can do instead is bind another variable, called `T` below, to the tail of `List`, like so:

```erlang
1> List = "/hi".
"/hi"
2> T=tl(List).
"/hi"
3> T.
"hi"
```

Comment: in this case also can use tl(List).

Comment: @Atomic_alarm Yes; it's more straightforward than pattern matching.

Answer (score 7):

Since strings in Erlang are lists of characters, a general way to delete the first occurrence of a character from a string is to use [lists:delete/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#delete-2):

```
1> List = "/hi".
"/hi"
2> lists:delete($/, List).
"hi"
```

The construct `$/` is the Erlang character literal for the `/` character.

Note that this approach works no matter where the character to be deleted is within the string:

```
3> List2 = "one/word".
"one/word"
4> lists:delete($/, List2).
"oneword"
```

Just remember that with this approach, only the first occurrence of the character is deleted. To delete all occurrences, first use [`string:tokens/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#tokens-2) to split the entire string on the given character:

```
5> List3 = "/this/looks/like/a/long/pathname".
"/this/looks/like/a/long/pathname"
6> Segments = string:tokens(List3, "/").
["this","looks","like","a","long","pathname"]
```

Note that `string:tokens/2` takes its separator as a list, not just a single element, so this time our separator is `"/"` (or equivalently, `[$/]`). Our result `Segments` is a list of strings, which we now need to join back together. We can use either [`lists:flatten/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#flatten-1) or [`string:join/2`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#join-2) for that:

```
7> lists:flatten(Segments).
"thislookslikealongpathname"
8> string:join(Segments, "").
"thislookslikealongpathname"
```

The second argument to `string:join/2` is a separator you can insert between segments, but here, we just use the empty string.

Comment: Your answer is much more comprehensive than mine is.

Comment: This should be marked as accepted answer.